# Windows Home Server backup solution

Tags: windows, backup

I admit this is not strictly a programming question, although I do use my WHS as a source repository server for home projects, and I'm guessing many other coders here do as well.

Does anyone have a recommendation for a good backup solution for the non-fileshare portion of Windows Home Server?  All the WHS backups I've seen handle the fileshares, but none of the system files or other administrative stuff on the box.

Thanks,
  Andy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[iDrive](http://www.idrive.com/) is Great and free under 2 gigs

Answer (score 2):

Windows Home Server is designed to not need a backup of the OS. If your system drive fails, install a new drive, and then boot the WHS OS setup disc and install the OS. It will find the data on the other drives and recreate all the shared folders. You do need to do some configuring once it is back up but that is pretty small compared to not having to back it up.

Comment: That assumes you use it "vanilla".  Because I'm a geek, I have other stuff installed that's not on the fileshares, for example websites, a home music server and a blog.  I'd like to be able to back up all the configuration for these things as well.

Answer (score 1):

One good solution for backing up the home server itself is to attach an external drive, say via USB 2.0 or eSATA.  For this to work, though, you need the supporting software like Norton Ghost or something similar installed on your WHS server.

Windows Home Server Power Pack 1 (aka WHS PP1) added a feature to perform backups of the WHS shared folders to an external drive -- as you mention, this feature is only intended to do the data side and not the OS.

If you have an HP MediaSmart server, you could try the method mentioned in [Quick & Easy Windows Home Server Backup and Restore](http://forhackers.com/?p=12). The author said it worked for him, but of course, *caveat emptor.*  This technique has you creating a disk-image for your backup, and using that to restore from in the Recovery Disk / Restore disk process.

If you want a faster way to recover your OS and you do not have a Media Smart server, you can also check out these [instructions on how to use a USB flash drive for installing WHS](http://wiki.wegotserved.com/index.php?title=Turn_your_USB_Flash_Drive_Into_a_Windows_Install_Disk), and merge in the instructions found above for restoring a disk image vis-à-vis  the OS Recovery disk process.

Answer (score 1):

WHS OS backup solved by running two copies of WHS each on its own computer in a virtual machine with each WHS backing up the other (running in a VM makes the WHS a file thus able to be backed up and restored by WHS).